# Integration of an exponential function over a triangle. Numerically stable approximation to the infinite sum?

Tags: integration, polynomials, power-series

This question is motivated by my need to evaluate the following integral for general a and b, 
\begin{align}
I(a, b) &= \int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\;\int_{0}^{1-x}\mathrm{d}y
\left(
e^{ax + by}
\right) \\
&= \frac{a (1 - e^{b}) - b(1 - e^a)}{ab(a-b)}.
\end{align}

I could do cases for small a, b, and (a-b).  But, I'm wondering if there is a better way.  The $a$ and $b$ values are variable in a particular way,
$$
a=-\sigma \alpha
$$
and, 
$$
b=-\sigma \beta.
$$

The values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are fixed, but $\sigma$ can be any non-negative number.  I want a fast rule for evaluating the integral for any new $\sigma$.

One thing that I tried was expanding the exponential functions in power series.  This gives, 
$$
I(a, b) = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{a-b}\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{a^{n}-b^{n}}{(n+1)!} 
$$

Maybe I can cancel out the $(a-b)$ in the denominator and truncate take a partial sum?  It would be great if I could get an expression like the following, 
$$
I(-\sigma \alpha, -\sigma\beta) = 
c_{0}(\alpha, \beta) + c_{1}(\alpha, \beta) \sigma + c_{2}(\alpha, \beta)\sigma^{2} + \cdots, 
$$

so that I can just store the constants ($c_{0}$, $c_{1}$, $c_{2}$, ...) and evaluate a low order polynomial in $\sigma$.

Does anybody have any insight into how to calculate this integral quickly for new values of sigma?